# JavaFX AnimationTimer not stopping properly

Tags: java, javafx, task, java-threads

So, I am creating the snake game using JavaFX and I cannot seem to make the game pause properly, i.e. it pauses occasionally and other times, the game just ignores the pause. So, basically I have a `Main` class where I initialize all the GUI components, and it also acts as the controller for the javafx Application.

I have a `Button` named `gameControl` which starts/pauses the game, a variable `Boolean pause` which keeps track of the game states (new/paused/running), and the methods `startGame`, `pauseGame`.

The `gameControl` button's `EventHandler` is as follows:

```
gameControl.setOnClicked(event->{
    if(paused == null) startGame(); //new game
    else if(paused) continueGame(); //for paused game
    else pauseGame();               //for running game
});
```

The `startGame` function looks something like this:

```
void startGame(){
    paused = false;
    Snake snake = new Snake(); //the snake sprite
    //following gameLoop controls the animation of the snake
    gameLoop = new AnimationTimer(){
        @Override
        public void handle(long now){
            drawSnake(); //draws the snake on the game
            snake.move(); //move snake ahead

            //following code is for slowing down the gameLoop renders to make it easier to play
            Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<>(){
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    gameLoop.stop();
                    Thread.sleep(30);
                    gameLoop.start();
                    return null;
                }
            };
            new Thread(sleeper).start();
            //force garbage collection or else throws a bunch of exceptions after a while of running.
            //not sure of the cause...
            System.gc();
        }
    };
    gameLoop.start();
}
```

`AnimationTimer gameLoop` are variables of the class to allow calling from other functions.

And the `pauseGame` function:

```
void pauseGame() {
    paused = true;
    gameLoop.stop();
}
```

So, as I have said before the game doesn't pause everytime I hit the `gameControl` button, and I suspect it is due to the `Thread.sleep(30);` line inside the `Task` of the `gameLoop`. That being said, I am still not fully sure and have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition that `Thread.sleep(30);` may be causing an issue is on the right track. A user may click the button calling `pauseGame`, setting paused to true, and telling the gameloop to stop. If the new sleeper thread is started and sleeping at that moment it will call `start()` on the gameloop when it wakes up.

One option may be to simply check the value of `paused` in the sleeper task to determine if it should start the gameloop.

```
Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<>(){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        gameLoop.stop();
        Thread.sleep(30);
        if (!paused) {
            gameLoop.start();
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Given that the paused value is being set and read from multiple threads, I would recommend adding a mechanism to ensure you don't get non-deterministic behavior. Swapping the Boolean to an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) is a straight forward option for ensuring consistency.

Comment: In this case it is probably good enough to make the boolean volatile, but if the game driven by an AnimationTimer all the relevant code should be happening on the Platform thread.  The use of the sleeper Task is just wrong in every way.

Comment: @swpalmer makes a good point in his answer and provides a compelling refactoring opportunity.

Answer (score 5):

What type is 'paused' ?  You check it for null, but then treat it as a boolean.. I can't understand why it would be a big 'B' Boolean object wrapper instead of the primitive boolean type.

This:

```
        //following code is for slowing down the gameLoop renders to make it easier to play
        Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<>(){
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                gameLoop.stop();
                Thread.sleep(30);
                gameLoop.start();
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Is an absolutely horrible way to throttle the speed.  Let your game loop run, check the time on each loop to see if enough time has elapsed that you should update things.  Your animation timer will drive the game.  You don't want to pause the main platform thread, you don't want to pause any worker threads that are handling tasks.  If you are scheduling tasks have them scheduled to run at the intervals that you want - don't throttle the thread in the call() method.

What you really want is something like this:

```
//following gameLoop controls the animation of the snake
gameLoop = new AnimationTimer(){
    @Override
    public void handle(long now){
        if ((now - lastTime) > updateIterval) {
            drawSnake(); //draws the snake on the game
            snake.move(); //move snake ahead
            lastTime = now;
        }
```

You could even make that a loop to "catch up" in case the Animation timer fell behind for some reason:

```
        while ((now - lastTime) > updateIterval) {
            drawSnake(); //draws the snake on the game
            snake.move(); //move snake ahead
            lastTime += updateIterval;
        }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. This is also a valid solution.

I didn't think of it like this before, probably because I sort of picked it up from another answer here on stackOverflow